# To solve following system of equivalences of integers

Tags: number-theory, congruences

To solve following system of equivalences of integers

$x \equiv 2 \pmod {15}$

$x \equiv 4 \pmod {21}$

The number of solutions in x, where $1\leq x\leq 315$ is

A. 0

B. 1

C. 2

D. 3

So i have to find number of numbers such that when 2 and 4 are subtracted from them they get divided by 15 and 21. But how do i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: $x\equiv 2\pmod{15}$ iff $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod 5$.

Comment: By congruences, we get $3$ divides $x-2$ and $3$ divides $x-4$, so $3$ divides $2$. (??)

Comment: @vadim123 Okay so one answer is 107.I found multiple of 3,5,7 and added 2 to it.Is this the way? Thanks

Comment: 107 is not answer to second!

Comment: Step 2: $x\equiv 4\pmod{21}$ iff $x\equiv 4\pmod{3}$ and $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @vadim123 i  combined step 1 and 2. Where is mistake

Comment: Step 3: Combining steps 1 and 2 we see that $x\equiv 4\pmod{3}$ and also $x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, which is not possible.

Comment: @vadim123 okay i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $x=2+15k_1$ and $x=4+21k_2$ from here we get $$15k_1-21k_2=2$$ with $k_1,k_2$ integer numbers. what can we say about the solutions of this equation?